# TPC mapping gets Method not found: MapInheritedProperties() exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

As I try to create a `TPC` mapping in `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>`, `EF 6.1.1` gets me the fallowing exception:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.EntityMappingConfiguration`1<!0>
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.EntityMappingConfiguration`1.MapInheritedProperties()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I mapped `TPC` via ignoring base classes in my `DBContext` class , and just mapping concrete classes.